# Calling a method after a delay?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, uiactivityindicatorview

How can I call a method after a short delay?  (For example, after resignFirstResponder is called.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u can call method after delay using perform select: like

```
[self performSelector:@selector(keyboardShow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either timer like this

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(taskOnTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

OR use this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playPages) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```